# How do I model this cockpit?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I tried subsurf then booleans, but they create N gons and shading issues no matter what. Any other solution?[image]

Comment: When I type "blender cockpit" into youtube's searchbar, there are literally dozens of videos popping up describing the process specifically. The more abstract term for it is "hard surface modelling" which brings another couple of hundred results. Anyway, you neither need subsurf nor booleans in the first stage.

Answer (score 1):

From making cockpits before, I can tell you that they are tricky. I would advise you to use subsurf, and turn on autosmooth under *Object Data* > *Auto Smooth*.

Autosmooth should be default, as it is far more useful than smooth shading alone. I just got used to turning it on after a while.

[image]
A shape like this one can be obtained quite simply using that technique, and won't contain shading errors.

Making the cockpit first, then using it as a boolean is probably a good solution. If quads are an issue, it's always possible to triangulate later. Also look into *Voxel Remesh* https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9dEqM3H31g&t=1322s

Comment: Thanks for your help and I will consider this option. However, from my past attempts, booleans have created shading issues (mostly hard edges even with smooth shading on) and triangulating the mesh doesn't fix it.

Comment: That would usually happen because the boolean intersects in weird ways. Making sure that the boolean lines up with the vertices can help with that. If not, it may be useful to separate the cockpit part of the mesh using the rip command `V` and modeling by hand.

Comment: Even with the boolean lining up with the mesh, issues are still present. I will try the rip command